# Javascript To Toggle Multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some Javascript code that targets multiple buttons. When clicked, the content should appear, which it does. However, i'm struggling to create the code that when the buttons are clicked again, the content is hidden.

I've included the Javascript, content and css for the elements i want to be toggled. Cheers.

Note: Code has to be in Javascript

```js
function openTab(click, openTab) {
  var i, content, link;
  content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  links = document.getElementsByClassName("links");
  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].className = links[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(openTab).style.display = "block";
  click.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.content {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #e8eaed;
  display: none;
  border-top: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section class = "Container">
    <div class="tabs">
      <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'About')">About</button>
      <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'Hire')">Why You Should Hire Me</button>
      <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'Contact')">Contact</button>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="Container2">
  <div id="About" class="content">About</div>

  <div id="Hire" class="content">Hire</div>

  <div id="Contact" class="content">Contact</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add your code which contains class `links` elements

Comment: did you try `toggleClass();` in `JQuery`

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with relevant HTML to show what to click

Comment: Use classlist and toggle https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Who is calling `openTab` function

Comment: @brk  See revised question

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable which represents whether the elements are hidden or not. Also, you could try to use `classList` to add/remove classes from elements with multiple class names, rather than `className` string manipulation, if at all possible.

You can use [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to easily switch classes:

```
let hidden = false;

function openTab(click, openTabId) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(
    content => content.style.display = hidden ? 'block' : 'none'
  );
  document.querySelectorAll('.links').forEach(
    link => link.classList.toggle('active')
  );

  document.getElementById(openTabId).style.display = "block";
  click.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
  hidden = !hidden;
}
```

Better yet, encapsulate the `hidden` variable in `openTab`, since it's not useful in the outer scope:

```
const openTab = (() => {
  let hidden = false;
  return (click, openTabId) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(
      content => content.style.display = hidden ? 'block' : 'none'
    );
    document.querySelectorAll('.links').forEach(link => {
      if (hidden) link.classList.add('active');
      else link.classList.remove('active');
    });

    document.getElementById(openTabId).style.display = "block";
    click.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
    hidden = !hidden;
  }
})();
```